# Producing confusion matrix for test dataset after TFlite modelmaker training

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, tensorflow-datasets, confusion-matrix

I try to train a classification model with 4 classes. I want to quantify the quality when I vary the input (different data treatment, class assignment) by producing a confusion matrix for each variation. I use modelmaker for the training.

Here's the code for training:

```
data = DataLoader.from_folder(data_root)
train_data, rest_data = data.split(0.7)
validation_data, test_data = rest_data.split(0.5)

model = image_classifier.create(train_data,validation_data=validation_data,epochs=20)
```

I had some issues finding exactly how to get the test_data labels and labels from predictions based on the test_data, but I do it like this in the end:

```
classes=model.index_to_label
ds = test_data.gen_dataset()

test_labels=[label for i, (image, label) in enumerate(ds.take(len(ds)))]
test_labels=[labs[0].numpy() for labs in test_labels]

test_pred=model.predict_top_k(ds)
test_pred=[classes.index(pred[0][0]) for pred in test_pred]

tf.math.confusion_matrix(test_labs,test_preds,num_classes=4)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data)
```

Looking at both lists (labels and pred), they look quite different, and the matrix confirms it:

```
[[  0,   0, 256,  26],
 [  0,   0, 240,  26],
 [  0,   0,  63,   0],
 [  0,   0, 240,  43]]
```

However, if I run the evaluation, I get 91% accuracy, similar to the validation results, which isn't reflected in the matrix at all. It is especially weird that I have no predictions for 0 and 1, otherwise I would have suspected something is just shuffled.

I believe I must have done some mistake getting the predictions, but since I am quite new to the modelmaker imageclassifier I have a hard time going further than what I did above.

Comment: @MasoomBadi no, unfortunately not. Modelmaker seems weird, since it has an integrated confusion matrix function but just for audio models.